# is a closed form solution possible?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, prime-numbers, closed-form

I have a facination with prime numbers and unsolved problems, and i ended up creating a formula that returns the index of any prime number. The main problem is I don't know if the summations if its possible to remove the summations, as the further away an inputted number is from 0, the more addition you need to do for the summations. it's also possible to use modulo instead of gcd, though i don't know the effect it would have.
the equation in question:
$$
f\left(n\right) = 
 \begin{cases}
  \left(
   \sum\limits_{l = 1}^{\lceil\sqrt{n}\rceil}
    \begin{cases}
     1,  \mbox{if}\ \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{\lceil\sqrt{l}\rceil}
     \operatorname{gcd}\left(n,i\right) = \lceil\sqrt{l}\rceil
     \\[2mm]
     0  \mbox{  otherwise}\
    \end{cases}
   \right), 
  \mbox{if}\ \sum\limits_{i=1}^{\lceil\sqrt{n}\rceil}
  \operatorname{gcd}
   \left(
    n,i
   \right)
  =
   \lceil
    \sqrt{n}
   \rceil
  \\[2mm]
  0 \mbox{ otherwise}\
 \end{cases}
$$

if the equation doesn't work, if i'm wrong, if you need clarification, etc. just let me know, I'd be happy to answer

Comment: What is the "index of any prime number" ?

Comment: @Peter In a list, an index is the positional indicator of an element in the list, so if we have list $A = [ a, b, c, d]$ the index of $a$ is $1$. similarly if we have a list of all prime numbers $[2, 3, 5, 7, 11 … \infty]$ the index of 101 is 25 as it is the 25th prime number. sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. By the way , $101$ is the $26$ th prime number. The index of the prime $p$ is just $\pi(p)$ , a closed form for this function is not known although there are efficient methods to compute it upto quite high limits.